# How to use RegEx find/replace in WingIDE (or Notepad++) to replace part of string with wildcard?

Tags: regex, replace, ide, find, notepad++

I'm trying to figure out how to add an argument after *self* for all methods in a large class.

For example, I'd like:

```
def PrbsPolySet(self, nValue)
```

...to become:

```
def PrbsPolySet(self, nLane, nValue)
```

Using RegEx find/replace in Wing or Notepad++, I can find the strings using a wildcard by entering this in the search box:

```
def.*\(self
```

But I can't figure out what to enter in the replace box so *self* is replaced by *self, nLane*.

Comment: Do this `def.*\(\Kself` then replace with `self, nLane`

Answer (score 0):

You could consider using back-references, search for:

```
def.*\(self
```

and replace it with `$0, nLane` (`$0` refers to entire match)

Or alternatively you could use `\K` token to left cursor at a position then insert your text right there:

```
def.*\(self\K
```

and replace with `, nLane`

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I think that the regex you typed in some cases will not work. Better to give less priority to the wildcard by adding a ?, so `def.*?\(self` is better.

Moreover, the classic way to go is to reference the matching group. Now, the standard is that `$0` matches all the captured string. Substituting `0` you can mean the various capturing groups in your regexes.

So, find
`def.*?\(self`

and replace with
`$0, nLane`